# Is possible add multiple projects at the same path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have four projects.

First, Its called Portal and have some logical components.
And the others manage other things.

Each of them has its own routes, but I would like to create a higher o superior routes to nav between all of them.

How can create that path to access to each project I dont have the component??

For example,

I want in one path have:

```
/portal    
  /login    
  /home
  /error 
/project1 
/project2 
/project3
```

This will be in portal, but in portal I dont have a Component called roject1.

`<Route exact path="/project1" component={Project1} />`

How can create that path to access to each project I dont have the component??
Or I should create it and make a redirect to Project1??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you should create separate folders. It is generally bad practice to leave different projects in a single folder.

You can directly call files to be used with `import { functionName } from './directory';`

(further explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file))